# Protobuf with many unknown types

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

What is the best approach when I do not know at runtime which types are de/serialized with protobuf?

Currently I am playing with the idea to extend the RuntimeTypeModel in the type initializers of the types which are candidates for serialization which seems to work pretty well for serialiation. But when deserializing in a different process I would need to load the same type model from somewhere which was used to serialize the types. Is it possible to serialize the RuntimeTypeModel to disk to reuse it later when the serialized data is read again from disk? Ideally I would put the model into the serialized stream as well to have a full self describing object model. Or would I need to record the steps and put this data in front of my serialized stream?

One could create a header which contains the offset to the real data and the runtime type model and the length which would be pretty nice. Or is there a better approach how to deal with a plug in architecture where at serialization time I have all types registered but during deseralization I might stil need to load some types from their respective assemblies because the code was not yet touched?

```
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace protobuf
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public interface IAbstraction
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Base : IAbstraction
    {
        static Base()
        {
            ProtobufTypeModels.MainModel.Add(typeof(IAbstraction), true).AddSubType(101, typeof(Base));
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2, AsReference =true)]
        public List<IAbstraction> Instances = new List<IAbstraction>();
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Next : Base
    {
        static Next()
        {
            ProtobufTypeModels.MainModel.Add(typeof(IAbstraction), true).AddSubType(100, typeof(Next));
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string NextName { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ProtobufTypeModels
    {
        public static readonly RuntimeTypeModel MainModel = TypeModel.Create();
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base b = new Base { Name = "Alois" };
            b.Instances.Add(new Next { Name = "Base", NextName = "Christian" });
            b.Instances.Add(new Base { Name = "SecondBase", Instances = b.Instances });
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            ProtobufTypeModels.MainModel.Serialize(mem, b);
            mem.Position = 0;
            var deser = (Base) ProtobufTypeModels.MainModel.Deserialize(mem, null, typeof(Base));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Random thought: you *could* use `.Compile(serializerName,dllPath)` after you've finished the initialization and write the baked serializer to disk; then you can reference it, use `new SerializerName()` to create the instance, and use the `.Serialize` etc methods *from there*. The dll will never change. This also means it never has to process *any metadata* ever again; no reflection, no IL emit, etc.

Other than that: we *could* possibly do something more gentle in terms of storing the configuration, but: protobuf-net doesn't currently add anything directly to support it, and it would probably be more relevant for you to have your own bespoke configuration data that you simply consume at startup.

Comment: Serializing the assembly is not the best thing since for a long running process where I need to load for every saved file a new assembly I could run into memory leak issues due to too many (thousands) of loaded assemblies into the current AppDomain. I think I will stick to record the Model.Add and AddSubtype calls and store these parameters in front of the stream to do an API call replay when I need to deserialize the types again.